# Creating user Story with least Rank

Tags: web-services, rest, rally

By Default, any user story created gets the highest Rank in an iteration. But my requirement is to add the user story at the bottom of iteration , not on Top, means with least rank. How can I manipulate the Rank of a User Story. In WSAPI 2.0 , I see there is an attribute - DragAndDropRank, but the value is not an integer and older version of WSAPI (1.3) was having Rank attribute, which can be manipulated. Any suggestions on implementing this would be helpful for WSAPI 2.0. Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your story you can supply `rankTo` query string parameter to control this:

```
rankTo=BOTTOM
```

You can also always rank an item relative to another item using the `rankAbove` or `rankBelow` query string parameters:

```
rankBelow=/defect/12345
```

`rankAbove` and `rankBelow` work on updates as well, while `rankTo` is only supported for creates.  We should really probably document those somewhere in the WSAPI docs somewhere...